# Java plugin in Google Chrome is not being loaded

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins

Google Chrome is not loading the Java plug-in properly. When I try it in Mozilla Firefox, it works perfectly on every site. I tried re-installing Chrome, but even that didn't help.

Comment: Does `chrome://plugins/` show that Java is enabled?

Comment: Also make sure that plugins are enabled at chrome://chrome/settings/content, and there's nothing under Plug-in Exceptions

Comment: what operating system are you running? The answer would likely be different if you're on Windows or Linux or OS X

Comment: I don't know about the OP, but I have this symptom on OSX Mountain Lion. Java does not show up in chrome://plugins/ and there are no mentions, for good or ill, under settings.